Why are changes visible on my server's IP (http://<your-ip>:5000) but not on my domain?
I've deployed a React app on my server and am using Nginx to serve the static files. The frontend is being served using http-server on port 5000, and Nginx is configured to proxy requests to that port. I can see the latest updates when I access the app using the server's IP (http://:5000), but the changes are not reflected when I access the app via the domain (https://).
Here's what I've done so far:
I ran npm run build and confirmed the build files are up-to-date in the /var/www//frontend/build directory.
I configured Nginx to serve the static files from the build/ directory and proxy API requests to localhost:5001.
Nginx is listening on port 443 for HTTPS traffic.
I restarted Nginx and cleared the browser cache, but still, the changes are not visible on the domain.
I can see the correct files loading from the IP address, but not from the domain.
Nginx Configuration:
nginx
server {
    server_name <your-domain>;

    root /var/www/<your-site>/frontend/build;
    index index.html;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.html;
        add_header Cache-Control "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";
    }

    location /api/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:5001/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/<your-domain>/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/<your-domain>/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name <your-domain>;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

Things I've tried:
Restarting Nginx and PM2.
Clearing my browser cache and using Incognito mode.
Checking the file timestamps to confirm the build folder is up-to-date.
Any ideas on what could be causing this discrepancy? Why do the updates show up when accessing the app via the IP but not the domain?
